# Need to map csv file to target table dynamically

Tags: database, csv, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have several CSV files and have their corresponding tables (which will have same columns as that of CSVs with appropriate datatype) in the database with the same name as the CSV. So, every CSV will have a table in the database.

I somehow need to map those all dynamically. Once I run the mapping, the data from all the csv files should be transferred to the corresponding tables.
I don't want to have different mappings for every CSV.

Is this possible through informatica?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: as said by navjot I will suggest you to write a bteq script for each file will have a better performance than mapping to load files  and can be handled dynamically ,
also you can write a script where you will pass number of columns as input and it will generate a fastload script for a particular type of file.

Answer (score 1):

PowerCenter does not provide such feature out-of-the-box. Unless the structures of the source files and target tables are the same, you need to define separate source/target definitions and create mappings that use them.

However, you can use [Stage Mapping Generator](http://powercenternotes.blogspot.ch/2013/05/stage-mapping-generator.html) to generate a mapping for each file automatically.

Answer (score 1):

PMy understanding is you have mant CSV files with different column layouts and you need to load them into appropriate tables in the Database.

Approach 1 : If you use any RDBMS you should have have some kind of import option. Explore that route to create tables based on csv files. This is a manual task.

Approach 2: Open the csv file and write formuale using the header to generate a create tbale statement. Execute the formula result in your DB. So, you will have many tables created. Now, use informatica to read the CSV and import all the tables and load into tables.

Approach 3 : using Informatica. You need to do lot of coding to create a dynamic mapping on the fly.

Proposed  Solution  :
mapping 1 : 
1. Read the CSV file pass the header information to a java transformation 
2. The java transformation should normalize and split the header column into rows. you can write them to a text file
3. Now you have all the columns in a text file. Read this text file and use SQL transformation to create the tables on the database

Mapping 2

Now, the table is available you need to read the CSV file excluding the header and load the data into the above table via SQL transformation ( insert statement)  created by mapping 1

you can follow this approach for all the CSV files. I haven't tried this solution at my end  but, i am sure that the above approach would work.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not using any transformations, its wise to use Import option of the database. (e.g bteq script in Teradata). But if you are doing transformations, then you have to create as many Sources and targets as the number of files you have.

On the other hand you can achieve this in one mapping.
1. Create a separate flow for every file(i.e. Source-Transformation-Target) in the single mapping.
2. Use target load plan for choosing which file gets loaded first.
3. Configure the file names and corresponding database table names in the session for that mapping.

Answer (score 0):

If all the mappings (if you have to create them separately) are same, use Indirect file Method. In the session properties under mappings tab, source option.., you will get this option. Default option will be Direct change it to Indirect.

I dont hav the tool now to explore more and clearly guide you. But explore this Indirect File Load type in Informatica. I am sure that this will solve the requirement.

Comment: Indirect file method will solve only when the structure of all the files will be same.

Answer (score 0):

I have written a workflow in Informatica that does it, but some of the complex steps are handled inside the database. The workflow watches a folder for new files. Once it sees all the files that constitute a feed, it starts to process the feed. It takes a backup in a time stamped folder and then copies all the data from the files in the feed into an Oracle table. An Oracle procedure gets to work and then transfers the data from the Oracle table into their corresponding destination staging tables and finally the Data Warehouse. So if I have to add a new file or a feed, I have to make changes in configuration tables only. No changes are required either to the Informatica Objects or the db objects. So the short answer is yes this is possible but it is not an out of the box feature.